# Define class with itself as generic implementation. Why/how does this work?

Tags: c#, .net, prism

I've normally been creating Prism Events used by the EventAggregator like:

`public class SomeEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<SomeEventArgs> { }`

```
public class SomeEventArgs
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But while looking at a co-workers code I noticed they did:

```
public class SomeEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<SomeEvent>
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I guess my first question is why does this even compile?  It seems to me that it's implementing a class that isn't defined yet.  And second, does it negatively affect the application at all, is it negligible, or better?

Comment: Note: it's not actually *implementing* the class, just making use of it.  SecondNote: I agree this is weird looking (+1).  Implementation vs. usage in a base class is different, but strange.

Comment: Welcome to the [*Curiously recurring template pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I guess my first question is why does this even compile?

Which rule in the spec do you believe it's violating?

> It seems to me that it's implementing a class that isn't defined yet.

I think you'd have to specify the *exact* meaning of each of those terms for the statement to be judged as accurate or not. The compiler knows about `CompositePresentationEvent` as it's declared elsewhere (presumably) and it knows about `SomeEvent` because that's the class *being declared*. It's like having a field of type `Foo` within a class `Foo` - entirely valid.

It's also very *useful* to be able to do this - particularly for comparisons. For example:

```
public sealed class Foo : IComparable<Foo>
```

says that any instance of class `Foo` knows how to compare itself with another instance, so it can be used for sorting in a type-safe way. In the case of structs, this also allows you to reduce boxing, as calling `x.CompareTo(y)` won't need any boxing when `x` is known to be of a type which implements `IComparable<>` appropriately.

Note that types can get *far* more interestingly and confusingly recursive. Take this (slightly modified) example from [my port of Protocol Buffers](http://protobuf-csharp-port.googlecode.com):

```
public interface IMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>
    where TMessage : IMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>
    where TBuilder : IBuilder<TMessage, TBuilder>

public interface IBuilder<TMessage, TBuilder>
    where TMessage : IMessage<TMessage, TBuilder>
    where TBuilder : IBuilder<TMessage, TBuilder>
```

Here, the aim is to basically end up with two types - a "message" and a "builder" so that you can always construct each from the other. For example:

```
public class Foo : IMessage<Foo, FooBuilder>
{
    ...
}

public class FooBuilder : IBuilder<Foo, FooBuilder>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It even has a name.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern